# Why do I get a "403 Forbidden" error when visiting meta over https?

Tags: bug, status-deferred

The title says it all, really: I visit http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com and I have no problems; I try to go to https://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com and I first get a "bad cert" warning followed (if ignored) by a 403 error.

Why is that?

Comment: Probably not the way the site was written for.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann ? I regularly use https: //aviation. and https: //chat. with none of the above issues

Comment: I meant that meta was not written with https capability.

Comment: uhm, I do not think so, I have used meta over https for a while before I ever got this errors

Comment: I have always gotten that error whenever trying to visit any of the sites' meta on https

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265918/accessing-per-site-metas-gives-403-forbidden-from-cloudflare-nginx

Comment: I've heard us talk about doing things like reversing the subdomain order from `meta.aviation.se` to `aviation.meta.se` that way we could get a wildcard cert for `*.meta.se`. Improving our SSL support is definitely on the roadmap, but I don't think we've landed on any decisions yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTPS on meta sites has always been problematic due to the way the certificates are issued and how the sites are structured.  From [the meta post fooot linked in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265918/accessing-per-site-metas-gives-403-forbidden-from-cloudflare-nginx) (posted by [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear)):

> This is a result/side-effect of some changes Cloudflare made recently, but the fact of the matter is that we'd run into problems with HTTPS support on child meta sites eventually anyway: you can't have a wildcard in the middle of a cert, so meta.*.stackexchange.com could never be a thing and we're not about to start registering/maintaining 100+ certs.
>
> So. We're working on moving meta sites to a different URL scheme (*.meta.stackexchange.com) to get around this. It's a move that was planned earlier, but was held back by universal login... which is now functionally complete. Unfortunately, there's a bunch of other stuff going on at the same time, so this switch is unlikely to happen until late October.
>
> In the meantime, I suggest not using HTTPS on meta sites since it's technically unsupported anyway

This isn't something that is limited to our meta, but is a network wide issue.  Until SE as a whole moves to the different naming scheme, this can continue to be an issue.